# Pong Script align in html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, alignment, pong

I am new to JavaScript and have a simple Problem.
I've got a pong.js and my index.html

The Pong Game should appear in the center, but I'm not able to achieve this. I've tried different things I've found on the Internet, but nothing helped me. I don't have any knowledge about Java. I think it's a simple code.

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Here is the index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
   <body>
     <script src="pong.js">
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my pong.js

```
// PONG SCRIPT V1

// FRAMERATE
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };



// RESOLUTION CANVAS
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');




// ANIMATE FUNCTION
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  animate(step);
};



// RENDER UPDATE
var step = function() {
  update();
  render();
  animate(step);
};



// BG COLOR
var update = function() {
};

var render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "#FFD439";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
};



//ADDING PADDLES AND THE BALL

// PADDLES
function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x_speed = 0;
  this.y_speed = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};



// PADDLES POSITION SCALE
function Computer() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle(10, 175, 10, 50);
}

function Player() {
   this.paddle = new Paddle(580, 175, 10, 50);
}



// PADDLES RENDER FUNCTION
Player.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};

Computer.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};



// BALL RADIUS COLOR SPEED
function Ball(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.x_speed = 4;
  this.y_speed = 0;
  this.radius = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.render = function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFF";
  context.fill();
};



// RENDER PADDLES AND BALL POSITION
var player = new Player();
var computer = new Computer();
var ball = new Ball(300, 200);

var render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "#FFD439";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  player.render();
  computer.render();
  ball.render();
};




// ANIMATING

// MOVEMENT BALL
var update = function() {
  ball.update();
};

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.x_speed;
  this.y += this.y_speed;
};



// COLLISION WALLS PADDLES
var update = function() {
  ball.update(player.paddle, computer.paddle);
};

Ball.prototype.update = function(paddle1, paddle2) {
  this.x += this.x_speed;
  this.y += this.y_speed;
  var top_x = this.x - 5;
  var top_y = this.y - 5;
  var bottom_x = this.x + 5;
  var bottom_y = this.y + 5;

  if(this.y - 5 < 0) { // hitting the upper wall
    this.y = 5;
    this.y_speed = -this.y_speed;
  } else if(this.y + 5 > 400) { // hitting the lower wall
    this.y = 395;
    this.y_speed = -this.y_speed;
  }

  if(this.x < 0 || this.x > 600) { // a point was scored
    this.x_speed = 4;
    this.y_speed = 0;
    this.x = 300;
    this.y = 200;
  }

  if(top_x > 300) {
    if(top_x < (paddle1.x + paddle1.width) && bottom_x > paddle1.x && top_y < (paddle1.y + paddle1.height) && bottom_y > paddle1.y) {
      // hit the player's paddle
      this.x_speed = -4;
      this.y_speed += (paddle1.y_speed / 2);
      this.x += this.x_speed;
    }
  } else {
    if(top_x < (paddle2.x + paddle2.width) && bottom_x > paddle2.x && top_y < (paddle2.y + paddle2.height) && bottom_y > paddle2.y) {
      // hit the computer's paddle
      this.x_speed = 4;
      this.y_speed += (paddle2.y_speed / 2);
      this.x += this.x_speed;
    }
  }
};



// CONTROLS
var keysDown = {};

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});

var update = function() {
  player.update();
  ball.update(player.paddle, computer.paddle);
};

Player.prototype.update = function() {
  for(var key in keysDown) {
    var value = Number(key);
    if(value == 38) { // up arrow
      this.paddle.move(0, -4);
    } else if (value == 40) { // down arrow
      this.paddle.move(0, 4);
    } else {
      this.paddle.move(0, 0);
    }
  }
};

Paddle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  this.x_speed = x;
  this.y_speed = y;
  if(this.y < 0) { // all the way to the top
    this.y = 0;
    this.y_speed = 0;
  } else if (this.y + this.height > 400) { // all the way to the bottom
    this.y = 400 - this.height;
    this.y_speed = 0;
  }
}



// COMPUTER AI
var update = function() {
  player.update();
  computer.update(ball);
  ball.update(player.paddle, computer.paddle);
};

Computer.prototype.update = function(ball) {
  var y_pos = ball.y;
  var diff = -((this.paddle.y + (this.paddle.height / 2)) - y_pos);
  if(diff < 0 && diff < -5) { // max speed left
    diff = -5;
  } else if(diff > 0 && diff > 5) { // max speed right
    diff = 5;
  }
  this.paddle.move(0, diff);
  if(this.paddle.y < 0) {
    this.paddle.y = 0;
  } else if (this.paddle.y + this.paddle.height > 400) {
    this.paddle.y = 400 - this.paddle.height;
  }
};
```

Comment: The Script works well as you can see here: http://www.einfachnurfilm.de/uploads/Pong%20Script/index.html

All I want is, that the pong game is in the center.

Comment: This is my script and my index file. The same you can see in the codes from the top. I just need a code to put it in the center.

Comment: I interpreted "should appear in the center, but I'm not able to achieve this" as "the script isn't appearing" rather than "the game isn't centered."

Comment: Sorry. There is no code to achieve this yet. I tried some from the Internet, but nothing happened. I am so new to the whole html and Java world.